# Dynamic mat-select option in form-array

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular6, formarray

I have a dynamic form group.

[sample ui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y95tj.png)

Both mat-select are dynamic. When I press the add button, it adds another array of the form with same elements and same dynamic fields.

In the first index of the array of the form group, when I change the value of the mat-select in the CATEGORY column, it will populate the JOB column according to values fetch from the database.

My issue is when I add another array of form group, the mat-select are still dynamic but when I change the value of the mat-select in the 2nd row, column CATEGORY, it changes every all the rows in JOBS column base on the fetch data in the first column.

HTML file

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="categories" 
          (selectionChange)="getJobs($event.value)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let cat of categories" 
                 [value]="cat.jobCatID">
                {{cat.name}}
              </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select formControlName="jobs">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let job of jobs" [value]="job.jobID">
            {{ job.name}}
          </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

TS file

```
getJobs(id){
return this.category.getJob(id).subscribe(
  data => {
      if(data.success){
        this.jobs=data.jobsCat.jobs
      }
  }
)}
```

is their anyway I can make the **jobs** variable dynamic, in order to have different objects variable with the same values in the ngFor for each JOBS mat-select?

Comment: Share the code how you are forming the `FormGroup` and `FormControl` multiple records.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.form = this._fb.group({
      name:this.applicantName,
      jobList:this._fb.array([this.getJobModel()])
    });
    this.getApplicant(id);
    this.getCategories();
  };

  addField(){
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['jobList'];
    control.push(this.getJobModel());
  }

  getItemsModel(){
    return this._fb.group({
      categories:[''],
      jobs:['']
    });
  }

Comment: Update this code into the question and more html code for `jobList` iteration.

Comment: Just the remaining formarray codes are lacking in my html. Is their anyway to make jobs variable in *ngFor to be dynamic or I want to concatenate the index in the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

All good now. I just made jobs into array.

```
jobs:any[]=[];
```

declared it like this. Then fetch used the index as parameter for a dynamic array.